# Nesting/joining a workspace input variable inside multi folder workspaceFolder variable?

Tags: visual-studio-code

Is there a way to nest an input variable inside other variables, particularly `${workspaceFolder}`? As an example .code-workspace file:

```
{
  "folders": [
    {
      "name": "Client",
      "path": "path/to/client/code"
    },
    {
      "name": "Server",
      "path": "path/to/server/code"
    },
    {
      "name": "Shared",
      "path": "path/to/shared/code"
    }
  ],
  "launch": {
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
      {
        "name": "(gdb) Launch",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "program": "apphere"
      }
    ],
    "inputs": [
      {
        "id": "pickProject",
        "type": "pickString",
        "description": "Select a project:",
        "options": [
          "Client",
          "Server"
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

All projects (Client and Server in this example) would share the same launch configurations, the only thing that would need to change is the `cwd` value. Unfortunately you cannot use `${workspaceFolder}` directly in a multi folder workspace as you receive this error:

> Variable ${workspaceFolder} can not be resolved in a multi folder workspace. Scope this variable using ':' and a workspace folder name.

What would be perfect is being able to do something like this:

```
"cwd": "${workspaceFolder:${input:pickProject}}"
```

Unfortunately this does not work. Is there another way to provide a dynamic scope for the workspaceFolder variable?

I did figure out one rather hacky way to handle this although it feels like there should be a better way: If you change the pickString input options to the folder paths and then change the debug cwd to `"cwd": "${workspaceFolder:Shared}/../../../${input:pickProject}"` you can arbitrarily pick one of the folders, traverse back out to the root workspace directory, and then append the ${input:pickProject} variable onto the end. In addition to the directory traversals, the debug choices you see will be "path/to/client/code" and "path/to/server/code" instead of the more clean "Client" and "Server". But at least it does seem to work, albeit not overly ideal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the extension [Command Variable](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable) you have possible solutions

##### [extension.commandvariable.file.fileAsKey](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable#fileaskey)

When you have a file open and current for Client or Server the F5 will select the correct `cwd` based on the path of the current file.

```
  "launch": {
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
      {
        "name": "(gdb) Launch",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "cwd": "${input:getCWD}",
        "program": "apphere"
      }
    ],
    "inputs": [
      {
        "id": "getCWD",
        "type": "command",
        "command": "extension.commandvariable.file.fileAsKey",
        "args": {
          "/client/": "/path/to/client/code",
          "/server/": "/path/to/server/code"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

##### [extension.commandvariable.pickStringRemember](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=rioj7.command-variable#pickstringremember-and-rememberpick)

If you want a pick list that shows `Client` and `Server` but returns the corresponding paths use:

```
  "launch": {
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
      {
        "name": "(gdb) Launch",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "cwd": "${input:pickPath}",
        "program": "apphere"
      }
    ],
    "inputs": [
      {
        "id": "pickPath",
        "type": "command",
        "command": "extension.commandvariable.pickStringRemember",
        "args": {
          "description": "Select a project:",
          "options": [
            ["Client", "/path/to/client/code"],
            ["Server", "/path/to/server/code"]
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```